# RxAndroid Event Bus and avoid duplicated events sent from an Adapter

Tags: android, events, rx-java

I implemented a simple event bus based on RxJava and this article: http://nerds.weddingpartyapp.com/tech/2014/12/24/implementing-an-event-bus-with-rxjava-rxbus/

Everything works fine except I have to listen / fire events from an adapter class, which is initialized by a fragment multiple times.
Because I am subscribed to each instance of that adapter, my events are being fired multiple times resulting in errors.

I would like to get subscribed to only 1 instance of that adapter and it has to be last one (not the first one).
So is there a way, that in case a new instance of the adapter is spawned, I can somehow detect if I already have been subscribed and update the subscription (or delete all previous ones of that adapter and just subscribe to the current one)?
Please note I also use the rxBus singleton in my other fragments / services, so I cannot just simply reset it entirely as then I will loose all other subscriptions not coming from the adapter.

Here is my code of the bus:

```
public class APIRxBus {
private static APIRxBus instance = null;
private final Subject<Object, Object> bus = new SerializedSubject<>(BehaviorSubject.create());

public static APIRxBus getInstance() {
    if (instance == null){
        instance = new APIRxBus();
    }
    return instance;
}

public void send(Object o) {
    bus.onNext(o);
}

public Observable<Object> toObserverable() {
    return bus;
}
```

}

and here of my subscription in the adapter class:

```
rxBus = APIRxBus.getInstance();

    rxBus.toObserverable()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object event) {

            if (event instanceof EVTSetPrintMode) {
                //...
            } else if (event instanceof EVTChangeDocumentImportance) {

                //...

            } else if (event instanceof EVTChangeDocumentVisibility) {
                //...
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What errors are you receiving? Those might be related to the `io` subscription. Subscribing to an adapter might be confusing to maintain, I would recommend to consider the adapter as the loading item and not load each item separate (or same behavior) - if possible.

Comment: I use this library: https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout and it initializes the adapter 3 times. The errors I get are my app errors due to the fact that the bus sends events 3 times and not one. The same situations was with Otto and Greenrabit EventBus. The swipelayout got animated unnecessarily as a side-effect.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `distinctUntilChanged(Func1)` if you can tell two subsequent events are the same or not, otherwise, you could try `debounce()` with some milliseconds.