# How to fix call duplicate method in RxBus in android

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

**WHY NOT HELP ME ANY PEOPLE???**

In my application i want use `RxBus` for handle events and **MVP** for design pattern! i want when click on one of `recyclerview` items, call one method in `fragment`.
For this i used **RxBus**!
I write below codes, but when click on items call 2 times method!!!

**RxBus codes:**

```
object RxBus {

    private val publisher = PublishSubject.create<Any>()

    fun publish(event: Any) {
        publisher.onNext(event)
    }

    fun <T> listen(eventType: Class<T>): Observable<T> = publisher.ofType(eventType)
}
```

**Adapter codes:**

```
class DashboardAvatarsAdapter constructor(
    private val context: Context, private val model: List<String>,
    private val url: String
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<DashboardAvatarsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_dashboard_avatars, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = model.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.avatarImg.showImageGlide(context, "$BASE_URL_IMAGE$url${model[position]}", holder.avatarLoader)
        holder.avatarImg.setOnClickListener {
            RxBus.publish(EventUpdateAvatar.UpdateAvatar(EVENTS_UPDATE_SEND_AVATAR, model[position]))
            Log.e("uploadAvatarLog", "Adapter")
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val avatarImg: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.avatarItemList_img)
        val avatarLoader: ProgressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.avatarItemList_progress)
    }
}
```

**Fragments codes:**

```
class DashboardAvatarsFragment : RoundedBottomSheetDialogFragment(), DashboardAvatarsContracts.View {

    @NonNull
    private lateinit var presenter: DashboardAvatarsPresenterImpl
    private lateinit var token: String
    private lateinit var layoutManager: GridLayoutManager
    private lateinit var adapter: DashboardAvatarsAdapter
    @NonNull
    private var disposable: Disposable? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard_avatars, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //Initialize
        presenter = DashboardAvatarsPresenterImpl(requireContext(), this)
        layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 5)
        //Get token
        token = GoodPrefs.getInstance().getString(PrefsKey.USER_JWT_TOKEN.name, "")
        //Send avatar
        disposable = RxBus.listen(EventUpdateAvatar.UpdateAvatar::class.java).subscribe {
            if (it.updateType == EVENTS_UPDATE_SEND_AVATAR) {
                Log.e("uploadAvatarLog", "Event")
                presenter.sendAvatarId(token, it.avatarId)
            }
        }

        //Get avatars list
        presenter.loadData(token)
    }

    override fun showAvatars(res: DashboardAvatarsResponse.Res) {
        adapter = DashboardAvatarsAdapter(requireContext(), res.avatars, res.baseUrl)
        dashboardAvatars_recyclerView.initRecyclerView(layoutManager, adapter)
    }

    override fun updateAvatar() {
        RxBus.publish(EventUpdateAvatar.UpdateAvatar(EVENTS_UPDATE_AVATAR, ""))
        Log.e("uploadAvatarLog", "Receive")
    }
}
```

I used `Log.e` for see log, but show me **duplicate** some **logs**!

```
2019-05-07 12:15:35.901 10259-10259/com.app.android E/uploadAvatarLog: Event
2019-05-07 12:15:35.902 10259-10259/com.app.android E/uploadAvatarLog: Adapter
2019-05-07 12:15:35.978 10259-10259/com.app.android E/uploadAvatarLog: Send
2019-05-07 12:15:35.978 10259-10259/com.app.android E/uploadAvatarLog: Event
2019-05-07 12:15:35.978 10259-10259/com.app.android E/uploadAvatarLog: Receive
2019-05-07 12:15:36.008 10259-10259/com.app.android E/uploadAvatarLog: Send
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RxAndroid Event Bus and avoid duplicated events sent from an Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742051/rxandroid-event-bus-and-avoid-duplicated-events-sent-from-an-adapter)